# Pass Massive list to View in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

New to ASP.NET MVC (using MVC3 with Razor now) and I'm confused on passing an object from the Controller to the View.  Specifically, I'm experimenting with MVC3 and Rob Conery's interesting Massive (http://blog.wekeroad.com/helpy-stuff/and-i-shall-call-it-massive).  I'm messing with a blog as a simple web application to experiment with.

HomeController.cs:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var table = new DynamicModel("mydb", tableName: "Posts");
            //grab all the posts
            var posts = table.All();
            ViewData["Posts"] = posts;

            return View();
        }
```

This part works great.  But how do I do this?

```
return View(posts);
```

If I reference `@posts.PostID` in the View, it errors out and says it's not valid.  So I tried creating a strongly typed view against the DynamicModel, but `posts` still wasn't there.

I know I can create a ViewModel and type the view against that and plug my data in there.  This is more about understanding how the Controller/View interact.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ASP NET MVC Templates is the solution.**

First of all, using `ViewData` is discouraged especially now in MVC 2.0 and 3.0 where there are many better ways to pass state to the view.

Strongly typed view is the way to go. But What if you have a collection to pass? Well, you still can create a strongly typed view for the collection (or generic list) but standard solution is to use ASP NET MVC templates (which are ascx files) for the item and not the collection and call RenderPartial on your parent view:

For example:

```
        <div>
            <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Bars.Count; i++)
               {%>
            <h3>
                <a href="#">Bar
                    <%: String.Format("{0:g}", Model.Bars[i].DocumentDate.ToShortDateString())%></a></h3>
            <div>
                <%: Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Bars[i].Content)%>
            </div>
            <%}%>
        </div>
```

There is a very good series on this topic [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html).

Comment: Fair enough -- but how do I pass the `posts` object to the partial view?  I created a strongly typed view and it failed ...

Comment: You don't you just say `DisplayFor` or `EditorFor`

Comment: I created a strongly-typed View against the DynamicModel object from Massive.  I also tried it against my MVC.Models.Posts object.  Then I ran `return View(posts);` and and tried to reference `posts` in the View.  It bombed, saying `posts` doesn't exist.  What do `DisplayFor` and `EditorFor` have to do with that?  I'm totally confused!

Comment: My solution was to use templates, which you would call DisplayFor or EditorFor. You can also RenderPartial.

Answer (score 10):

First of all you need to create a class. For example:

```
public class Post : DynamicModel
{
    public Post(): base("db")
    {
       PrimaryKeyField = "PostID";
    }

}
```

In the Controller you can have :

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var table = new Post();
            var posts = table.All();

            return View(posts);
        }
```

So you can create a Strongly Typed View and set the Model of the View to IEnumerable. The View will be like this :

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>

<h2>Index</h2>
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>@item.PostID</li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks GeoChatz! Didn't know about IEnumerable<dynamic>.