# ASP.NET Massive - How to create database to display VIEW

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, massive, northwind

Hello guys wanna ask help because I don't understand how to create database that I can use using MASSIVE.CS in ASP.NET MVC 3.

Im stuck in figuring out how I can implement this MASSIVE class to my MVC project and how connection string connects in northwind database. I only have [this tutorial https://github.com/robconery/massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive) but I'm still having problems understanding.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MovieMassive.Models;

namespace MovieMassive.Controllers
{
    public class MoviesController : Controller
    {

        MovieTable dbMovies = new MovieTable();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            dbMovies.Query("SELECT * FROM MovieTable");
            return View(dbMovies);
        }

        public ActionResult Add() {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

> Connection string:
>
> ```
> <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="data source=|DataDirectory|MyDatabase.sdf"  providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
> ```

MovieTable Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Massive;

namespace MovieMassive.Models
{
    public class MovieTable : DynamicModel
    {
        public MovieTable() : base("movieMassive", "MovieTable", "ID") { }
    }
}
```

Okay here's what I want, Can you help me how to run correctly the View `Index.cshtml`. The properties are not there yet. because don't know hot to implement it with database... Any help will be greatly appreciated..

```
@model IEnumerable<MovieMassive.Models.MovieTable>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>ReleaseDate</th>
        <th>Genre</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Rating</th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

I need this one to run correctly to create a basic CRUD using massive. Thanks in advance..

Comment: What, specifically, do you not understand?

Comment: @Michael Petrotta : DOn't know how to implement this Massive with a database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update to OP comment after code was updated into question

Jed, change your MoviesController to this

```
public class MoviesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MovieTable dbMovies = new MovieTable();
        dbMovies.All();
        return View(dbMovies);
    }
    ...
}
```

---

Visit TekPub.com, watch the MVC 2 vids (because they're free) as Rob Conery shows you how to implement the Massive file into an MVC app

Here's the direct link

[ASP.NET MVC Concepts - free](http://tekpub.com/view/aspmvc/1)

Rob's Massive.cs file is basically an ORM (Object Relational Mapping) tool that queries your datastore for tables and uses them as objects in your application.

Implementing it is easy. You need:

- ConnectionString in your web.config that points to your database. Here's a sample SQL connection string:

  ```
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyConnectionString" 
           connectionString="Data Source=DNSServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;user id=Username;password=Password" 
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  ```

If you are using something other than MS SQL you can visit connectionstrings.com for your specific platform

- Drop the Massive.cs file downloaded from GitHub into your application. How your solution is divided will make a difference as to where you add the file. If you are using only one project in your ASP.NET MVC app then you can just add it into the project root, or create a folder for it. Rob uses a folder called Infrastructure if I remember correctly.

NOTE - most real world applications are comprised of a UI project, a business logic layer and a data access layer. If you are using an N-Tier solution like this, then the Massive.cs file should go into your DAL.

- Your ready to go, that's all there is to implementing Massive!

### Usage

To use massive in your app just do something like this:
I'm using a simple example of a single project MVC app and not separating layers.

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    var table = new Products();
    var products = table.All();
    return View(products);
}
```

Again, this is not the strictest usage. You should learn all about using the MVC pattern and how to structure your solution/application into the correct design. Normally you would use a ViewModel that had properties of `Product` and then you would map the `products` returned from the Massive call to `table.All();` to your ViewModel

This was a simple crash course, hope it helps someone :-)

Comment: No problem, I know it's hard to get started without knowing where to turn. But StackOverflow is really geared towards questions that are less broad and expect the user to have done quite a bit of research on their own. Something like Massive.cs written by Rob Conery is kinda specific tho and I know there isn't much out there dealing with documentation on it.

Comment: That's a lot of video to dig through, for the answer to Jed's question. Since you seem to have some knowledge of this wrapper, can you reference anything more specific or targeted? Even better (since all links rot), how about writing something up here?

Comment: My hunch is he will be happy to have the extra free tutorials on top of finding the answer to his question :-)

Comment: @Michael Petrotta : Thank you very much because you care. I wrote down already the code. :-)

Comment: @AlfalfaStrange: Yes he used `Infrastructure` I have a sample project here but don't understand all of the codes. Thanks again for lighten up my understanding...

Comment: @Jed I updated my answer again dealing with your specific code problem

Comment: @AlfalfaStrange  One question. Do I need to create database using database manager? or write also codes to create database using Seed()/ Initializer like in the Entity Framework tutorial. Sorry, just a beginner. I can't open the video tutorial you gave, my internet is so slow.

Comment: @Jed no, Massive is doing that for you in a sense, you just define the tables like you did with the movie table and access them like that. You don't use EntityFramewith with Massive, you use either one or the other because they both are doing the same thing

Comment: @Jed see this Question on SO, it might help you out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485052/pass-massive-list-to-view-in-mvc3